# Problemas con CONCAT con Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, concat

Empece hace relativamente poco con MySQL y dentro de todo voy bien practicandolo, salvo por una cosa...

Vi varios tutoriales y ejemplos sobre la función CONCAT pero sigo teniendo el problema de que nunca me la reconoce el Dbeaver y me larga error en la sintaxis de esa parte.
Quisiera que me puedan ayudar a descubrir mi error.
Acá les dejo un ejemplo de lo que intente hacer:

```
SELECT CONCAT('firstname',' ','lastname') as Nombre_completo,
   LOWER(Email) as Email FROM customer WHERE Country='Brazil' ORDER BY lastname;
```

La idea es que salga el nombre y apellido concatenados, el mail en minusculas y solamente los clientes de Brasil.

Comment: firstname y lastname son nombres de columnas?

Comment: Exacto. Firstname contiene los nombres y lastname los apellidos.

Comment: Quítale las comillas entonces a ambas sino pudiera estar leyéndolas como simples cadenas de texto y no como columnas de tu tabla

Comment: Es perfectamente valido que ponga las comillas @BetaM

Comment: No @Reductor no es válido si son las comillas que el esta usando pues solo le imprimirá la palabra que paso dentro, si el quiere ponerles comillas deben ser: **``** las backticks prueba y tu mismo te darás cuenta

Comment: Tienes razón @BetaM,lo probé, te dejo un positivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pregunta indicas que CONCAT no esta funcionando en Dbeaver, sin embargo lo unico que debes cambiar de tu consulta es eliminar las comillas simples de `firstname` y `lastname` de esta manera:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) as Nombre_completo,
 LOWER(Email) as Email FROM customer WHERE Country='Venezuela' ORDER BY lastname;
```

Intente reproducir el problema utilizando HeidiSQL o MySQL Workbench y la consulta esta correcta, te adjunto una imagen de la salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es cierto, tenía razón @BetaM . Lo probe yo también y al final se resolvio. Gracias a todos!